# Giving XP to my ADC

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm a support main in a pretty low in ELO.  I don't play with other ADCs besides my brother or another great friend of mine.
While watching some of the LCS games, I noticed that the supports are usually way behind in experience points than anyone else on the team.

**How can I give my AD carry more experience in the laning phase while making sure they still do well?**
I don't want to stay and soak up the experience, or roam and leave my ADC to start losing.

Comment: play zilean. give xp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. Well, you can but it's risky, risky enough that it comes down to who is your ADC.

As you know by now (hence the question), two or more champions near a minion/champion death results in less experience gain. That is why a common tactic (not necessarly only in LCS) is to leave the ADC alone, in order for him to obtain more experience.

> How can I give my AD carry more XP in the laning phase and make sure they still do well instead of staying and soaking it up, or roaming and they start losing?

Well, for one there's **Zilean**'s passive like @*Dragonrage* mentioned in the comments, but I suspect you want a more definite answer than "play x champion".

What you need to ensure is that your ADC will still be able to farm without you, and that he won't die without you. In other words, you need to ensure that:

1. The enemy team isn't freezing the lane (He wouldn't be able to farm safely)
2. The enemy team isn't able to towerdive him (He would get killed)
3. Your ADC can effectively not push the wave (Would allow the enemy to freeze)
4. Your Jungler **doesn't** plan on going bot soon (If you leave he gets behind)
5. The enemy Jungler **doesn't** plan on going bot soon (3v1 towerdives arent' that risky)

---

There's also another situation which is jungling, depending on who your botlane is, you can sometimes go into the jungle and take a camp or two to gain some experience if you're zoned in lane. In this case both you and the adc would take a camp and get a small experience boost instead of gaining no exp at all. However this depends heavily on your own jungler's routes and what he's trying to do at that momment.

---

Finally the most important thing is: ***You are being useful***. There is no point in roaming to let your adc get level advantage if you're getting even further behind. Let's say you roam and your ADC is level 6. Their botlane is level 5 and you're level 4. They are ahead because they will have their ultimates on a 2v1 situation, or on a 2v2 situation before you have your own ultimate ability. As such you should only do those roams if you're being productive (Taking Dragon, Ganking Lanes, Peeling on jungle skirmishes)

Comment: aren't their items, masteries, and runes that provide increased XP/ timed XP for support roles along with items, mastieres, runes for gold? have the min/max numbers been worked out here? It may be possible to supplement this strategy with these items in order to close the gap?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I normally stay useful if I'm behind by playing supports with good, playmaking kits (Thresh, Alistar, Braum)

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer There's a rune that gives extra 2% experience (Total 6%, it's a quintessence). While it does give extra exp, it requires you to be already taking experience from somewhere. From level 5 to level 6 you need 100 exp, that's about 3 waves. Sure you may cover a bit, but not nearly enough (you get it about one-two minions faster, If duoing). Not to mention you lose lots of important stats

Comment: @Oak I'm guessing some of the ADCs that would be good for surviving in lane by themselves could be Jinx or Caitlyn, maybe Corki just because they're long range and can take CS from further way, to be safer?

Comment: @TrapHappy Yes, in a way; However Caitlyn can't clear waves that well and neither can jinx (at least under turret without running oom pretty fast). And Jinx is much riskier since she has no escapes and is even more vulnerable to being dove